# How to connect two Bluetooth BLE devices in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to use Bluetooth BLE to receive data from heart rate and send a command to second device. I write two program acccording to android sample(http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html).
first program is to use the android to receive heart from A device by bluetooth.
second program is to use the android to send command to B device by bluetooth.
I merge two Bluetooth service into one program. but it seems not work.
i created, one BluetoohManager, one BluetoothAdapter, two service classes,two BroadcastReceiver, two BluetoohDevices. I don't if it is the right way. it seems not work. Does anyone have some code example? or does someone can tell me how to modify the android code example (BluetoothLeGatt) to deal two bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 2):

We have some of the best libraries available for bluetooth communication, this might help you

[Bluetooth LE Library for Android](https://github.com/alt236/Bluetooth-LE-Library---Android)

[SmartGattLib](https://github.com/movisens/SmartGattLib)

[android-btxfr](https://github.com/simonguest/android-btxfr)

[Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary)

[Android-Bluetooth-Library](https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Bluetooth-Library)

Comment: Thank you!i will try those libery. could you tell me which one can implement multiple devices bluetooth connection?

Comment: I have not implemented any of it but it was in my list of useful libs so gave you , sample is given with it you can check it !